# How to set the placeholder as valid value if input is empty

Tags: angular, validation, placeholder, angular8, formbuilder

I have a simple form for a username with a placeholder value (suggested username) and want the user to be able to just click "Go", 
without adding a specific username, so the form should set the placeholder value as his username.

formBuilder:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  username: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('[A-Za-zäöüéèàáóúûñÄÖÜß]{3,20}$')
  ])]
});
```

The input: (For Example: suggestedUsername="JohnDoe12")

```
<ion-input color="light" type="text" formControlName="username" placeholder="{{ suggestedUsername }}"></ion-input>

<p *ngIf="form.username.errors && hasError">
   <ion-text color="danger" *ngIf="form.username.errors">
     Name is invalid! (letters only, 3 to 20 characters)
   </ion-text>
</p>

<ion-button (click)="save()">Go</ion-button>
```

When I just click "Go", the input counts as empty and I get the error. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You could either remove the required Validator from the form control, and patch the `username` value on your save function:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.pattern('[A-Za-zäöüéèàáóúûñÄÖÜß]{3,20}$')
  ])]
});
// ...
save() {
  if (!this.form.get('username').value) {
    this.form.patchValue({ username: this.suggestedUsername });
  }
  //...
}
```

or you could set the value from the beginning, but it could be a bad UX.